# Windows XP SP3 user profile issue

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles

The machine is Windows XP SP3, and according to them, the machine was reset (appears factory reset) after dealing with their ISP to upgrade their router. The represenitive connected and did something (I am unaware what).

However, I found the files, they are in `%systemdrive%/Documents and Settings/Administrator`.

The only problem is that the computer loads `%systemdrive/Documents and Settings/All Users`, and I am unsure how to get it to link to the correct files again.

The user only has an Administrator account, so how would I go about telling the OS to link to the files correctly?

Also I need it to link correctly to the Outlook 2007 files, so that all the emails can be seen; right now it tries to set up again.

Comment: what kind of files? dll? exe? I would use AutoRuns (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and see what is started when the computer reboots. And check the file paths... It could be an activeX, a service... check the install date with whatever is in the "Add/Remove Applications". Probably can google th e filenames in that folder to find out what it is, and maybe uninstall and reinstall correctly... be careful with AutoRuns though